# Unity3d Button do not respond to first click, need another one

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-ui

I have a gui (WebGL) with buttons that do not respond on first click.

This specific button:

[image]

...is a search button. The process is as follows:

1. Click on the yellow search button
2. Button turns green and inputfields are emptied to prepare for search type
3. When search criteria is typed in and button is clicked for the second time it turn yellow again and search is performed

...all this work with one exception and that is when I do the first click nothing is happening so I need to click one more time to catch the first click and the process starts. BTW, I have the same problem with the other buttons as well.

There is nothing above the button.

[image]

Here is some of the code associated to the button:

```
public void BTN_SearchPlayer()
{
    print("BTN_SearchPlayer");

    if (isFirstRun)
    {
        isFirstRun = false;
        btn_SearchPlayer.image.color = Color.green;
        GetComponent<Player>().BTN_ResetPlayerUI();
        GetComponent<Player>().pnl_LockPlayer.SetActive(false);
        GetComponent<GolfManager>().img_Lock.sprite = GetComponent<GolfManager>().sprt_UnlockedLock;

        // Enable tgl-groups and toggles switch off all tgls temporary
        GenderGrpTgl.GetComponentInChildren<ToggleGroup>().allowSwitchOff = true;
        GetComponent<Player>().tgl_Femail.isOn = false;
        GetComponent<Player>().tgl_Male.isOn = false;
        img_PlayerFrameAndGrp.GetComponentInChildren<ToggleGroup>().allowSwitchOff = true;
        GetComponent<Player>().tgl_ActivePlayer.isOn = false;
        GetComponent<Player>().tgl_ReservePlayer.isOn = false;
        GetComponent<Player>().tgl_InactivePlayer.isOn = false;
        GetComponent<Player>().tgl_Admin.isOn = false;
        GetComponent<Player>().tgl_MatchMgr.isOn = false;
        GetComponent<Player>().tgl_Buggy.isOn = false;

        txt_HcpTips.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        GetComponent<Player>().inp_CurrentHCP.contentType = TMP_InputField.ContentType.Standard;

    }
    else
    {
        result_List.Clear();
        isFirstRun = true;
        CheckWhatShouldBeSearched();

        DoTheSearch();

        txt_HcpTips.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

I do not see the print until click #2 so the firstRun bool is working..

I have also tested onClick event in code with the same result.